# Minimizing SVG file size

Tags: svg, filesize, adobe-illustrator

I am saving map images created in Adobe Illustrator as .svg documents.  What are some tips and tricks for making the file size as small as possible?

Comment: My favourite tool is Scour: http://codedread.com/scour/

If you feel like doing some more work by hand in a text editor, you can find lots of little tricks in the changesets and commit messages here too - but this requires learning some of the (fascinating!) SVG format details: https://github.com/johan/svg-cleanups/commits/

Comment: As SVG is a XML based file which can be manually edited by a web developer, how can this question be offtopic?

Comment: check out [Peter Collingridge's online tool](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser) for a quick solution.

Answer (score 31):

1. Turn off "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities", which includes an **enormous** proprietary pseudo-binary blob in your file.
2. GZIP your content (either explicitly, or via your web server settings) when the user agents you intend to view your work support this.
   *SVG is XML, and hence text, and hence quite compressible.*
3. Reduce unnecessary numeric precision. (You can do this either with the "Decimal Places" setting when saving from Illustrator, or by post-processing your file to reduce precision.)
   *For example, the following two paths are visually indistinguishable:*

   ```
   <path d="M102.6923828,391.6152344
    c56.8027344,115.9394531-3.8457031-246.1542969,105.3847656-217.6923828
    s218.4609375-53.0766602,243.8457031,40.7695313
    S541.9228516,411.6152344,435,527s-166.1538086,58.4609375-213.8461914-50
    C173.4614258,368.5385742,46.5385742,277,102.6923828,391.6152344z"

   <path d="M102.7,391.6c56.8,115.9-3.8-246.2,105.4-217.7s218.5-53.1,243.8,40.8
    s90,196.9-16.9,312.3s-166.2,58.5-213.8-50C173.5,368.5,46.5,277,102.7,391.6z"
   ```
4. Factor out repeated attribute-based styles into common CSS- or entity-based styles.
   *For example, you might replace*

   ```
   <rect fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="10px"   ... />
   <circle fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="10px" ... />
   ```

   *with*

   ```
   .bold { fill:red; stroke:black; stroke-width:10px }
   <!-- ... -->
   <rect class="bold"   ... />
   <circle class="bold" ... />
   ```
5. Factor out repeated transformations into grouped items.
   *For example, replace*

   ```
   <rect   transform="translate(102,-64) rotate(10.23)" ... />
   <circle transform="translate(102,-64) rotate(10.23)" ... />
   ```

   *with*

   ```
   <g transform="translate(102,-64) rotate(10.23)">
     <rect ... />
     <circle ... />
   </g>
   ```